# Configuring libinput-gestures for a MacBook like experience

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, lenovo, multi-touch

99% of the time I'm using my trackpoint, but sometimes its nice to use the trackpad. I'm running libinput as my driver, and found out that libinput-gestures should be able to give me multi-touch configurations. I have everything installed but how do i configure libinput-gestures to give me a MacBook like experience.

I would like to atleast enable 1 finger click, 2 finger right click, 2 swipe finger left to go back in the browser, and 4 finger swipe up to show all applications. Any other gesture would be nice too.

If there is another way of doing this, I'm all ears... or all eyes haha

Answer (score 6):

An excellent blog post that answers your question.

https://devhub.io/repos/bulletmark-libinput-gestures

I just finished configuring my system (MacBook Air) using this and Ubuntu Gnome 16.10.

BTW -- this is my first real commitment to Gnome as I normally use ubuntu unity DE... I choose to do this because while Unity has some built-in gestures for the touchpad, I didn't find them as good or as useful as those from the OS X.  Gnome appeared to have less conflict with the libinput-gestures.

I have happily got my system set up for vertical 3-finger up/down change desktop, 4-finger up to go to expo, 4-finger down for launchpad/dash, 3-finger left/right for browser and files/nautilus navigation, and 4-finger left for previous app and 4-finger right for alt-tab next app.  Had to do a custom configuration.

Finally to really get Gnome to work for me, I had to use several extensions.  Most notably:
+++ Workspaces to Dock (GREAT extension and probably could use all by itself because it can combine dock and workspaces in one.
++Dash to Dock
GnoMenu

Enjoy --- I know this is way late, but you or someone else may find it useful.

Comment: Which blogpost are you referring to ?

Comment: Sorry I neglected to add... it has been a while but i think it was this one.  Regardless... this is where i would go today for info on the utility.

https://devhub.io/repos/bulletmark-libinput-gestures